# change printer Paper size via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, size, media-queries

i have a div and need to print this. i changed size via @page to a5 but in print preview browser show this in a4 paper.

```css
   @media print {
            @page {
                margin-bottom: .5em;
                margin-left: .5em;
                margin-right: .6em;
                margin-top: .5em;
                size: A5;
                size: landscape;
            }
        }
```

is any way to change default paper size of printer via jquery?
thanks

Comment: Try setting margin zero.